# OrbitControls changing camera position

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm working on an academic project in THREE.js and Blender.
In my `main.js` I have the code to create a scene, create a renderer, a camera, orbit controls, etc...
The problem is, everytime I load the webpage, the camera is looking at a certain position `camera.lookAt(0,0,90)` but everytime I try to move the object, the camera looks at another position.

This is an animated gif that represents my problem
[image: This is an animated gif that represents my problem]

And this is the code I have:

```
var cena =  new THREE.Scene();
cena.background = new THREE.Color( 0xFFFFFF );
// Criar uma camara
var camara =  new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, 600/530, 0.1, 500);


var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
// preparar um renderer WebGL com um viewport 800x600 a adicioná-lo à pagina
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas: canvas, antialias: true });

renderer.setSize(600, 530); // tamanho do canvas (da área preta)
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true
renderer.gammaOutput= true
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio)


camara.position.x = 0;
camara.position.y = -5;
camara.position.z = -15;



// OrbitControls.js
var controlos = new THREE.OrbitControls(camara, renderer.domElement);

camara.lookAt(0, 0, 90)


// GLTFLoader (BLENDER PARA THREE.JS)
var carregador = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
carregador.load(
    'blender/mochila.glb', // Nome do ficheiro .gltf
    function(gltf){     // Adicionar o ficheiro à cena a ser renderizada
        cena.add(gltf.scene);
    }
);


// Adicionar pontos de luz
var luzPonto1 = new THREE.PointLight("white");
luzPonto1.position.set(5, -5, -5);
cena.add(luzPonto1);


// Adicionar pontos de luz
var luzPonto1 = new THREE.PointLight("white");
luzPonto1.position.set(-5, -5, 5);
cena.add(luzPonto1);

// Adicionar pontos de luz
var luzPonto1 = new THREE.PointLight("white");
luzPonto1.position.set(1, 1, 1);
cena.add(luzPonto1);

// Adicionar pontos de luz
var luzPonto1 = new THREE.PointLight("white");
luzPonto1.position.set(5, 5, 5);
cena.add(luzPonto1);

// Adicionar pontos de luz
var luzPonto1 = new THREE.PointLight("white");
luzPonto1.position.set(-5, -5, -5);
cena.add(luzPonto1);


function animar(){ 
    requestAnimationFrame(animar);
    renderer.render(cena, camara);
} 
animar();
```

**How can I keep the same initial position when I'm moving the object?**

Comment: You should not be calling `camera.lookAt()` in the render loop. Set `controls.target.set( 0, - 4, 1 ); controls.update();` right after you create the controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `lookAt()` method can be finicky.  First off, it's best to supply it with a vector object, in this case a `Vector3()`.  In terms of your problem where the camera seems to flip orientation, it may be that the orientation of your camera and the OrbitControls are having issues with which way is [up](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Object3D.up), although that shouldn't be the case. I'm also unclear on why you want the camera to look at the position `0, 0, 90`, when the object itself is at `0, 0, 0`?

Personally, however, I would use the [`target`](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/controls/OrbitControls.target) property that comes as an option with OrbitControls.  Something like `controlos.target = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);` should do.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I figured out that changing the `camera.lookAt()` code to the loop function works. Not the best solution still...

```
function animar(){ 
    camara.lookAt(0, -4, 1)
    requestAnimationFrame(animar);
    renderer.render(cena, camara);
} 
animar();
```